# Getting #1040 - Too many connections testing with 5000 VUs and JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am test Load Testing using JMeter around 265 or more users then it's not give me the result. and my database give the "#1040 - Too many connections".
it's work  fine for only 100 users .
so please tell me what can i do for test 1000 users or more..
My system config is 4gb Ram with core duel processor..
and I am a PHP Developer so not more knowledge in load testing and server configuration..

Answer (score 2):

By default MySQL supports 150 + 1 connections, this behavior is controllable via `max_connections` variable. See [C5.2.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) of MySQL documentation on how to increase it. If you're using defaults I guess that you'll also need to play with other parameters, read about variables having `innodb` prefix.

Similarly for Apache (if you're using Apache with PHP) default connections number is 256. See `MacClients`, `StartServers`, `MaxRequestsPerChild`, etc. directives.

JMEter bit. One instance of JMeter running on hardware you described won't be able to serve more than 100-150 threads, 300 is absolute maximum. You'll need to consider [JMeter Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) in order to create 5000+ users load. But you need to know the following:

1. Avoid "heavy" listeners like [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) (which is pretty good for debugging but will definitely cause crash in case of severe load)
2. Avoid the majority of "graph" listeners
3. Ensure that you have `mode=StrippedBatch` option set in `user.properties` file.
4. Follow other [JMeter Performance and Tuning](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) tips

Comment: Regarding 300 is absolute maximum, I absolutely disagree, I won't downvote although :-)

Comment: I also think you can hit more than 300 threads with a 4GB dual core machine. 300 might be the max for a very resource intensive script. Just make sure you're not hitting JMeter resource limits. For details see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246840/is-the-jmeter-load-server-affecting-my-results

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, if there's really one, lies in the usage you make of your database. It has nothing to do with the stress tool you're using. Too many connections might mean that you have to increase the number of connections your MySQL instance accepts, or that you're not properly closing connections and are leaking them, or simply that your application is not efficient enough to handle such load.

In any case, investigate on your application side, not on the stress tool.

Comment: Thanks For your Reply.. so please tell me how can i  test many users on this JMeter tool..